# Progress HUD doesn't show on the correct View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using the SVProgressHUD class ( https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD ) and I got a Main View Controller with a button on it which is connected using a segue push with another view controller.
In the Main View Controller I added this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
   NSLog(@"segue test");
}
```

What I want to do is, before the other View Controller is loaded the HUD needs to be display. If I run my program, it first prints out the NSLog "segue test" and after that it prints out the NSLogs from the other View Controller, the problem is the HUD doesn't directly when the button is pushed, it shows when the other View Controller is loaded...

This is what I have now:

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/jphh0n.png]

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/vzx16a.png]

This is what I need:

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/2vcb1aw.png]

And afther the blue screen loads, the "Loading" HUD needs to dissapear.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of connecting the segue directly from the button, you can connect the segue from the view controller class. Make sure you give the segue a name, because you need this name so you can call it later.

Then, you can connect your button to an `IBAction` first that will load first what you are loading. After the loading has completed, you can dismiss the progress HUD and call the segue.

```
- (IBAction)loadStuff:(id)sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
    [self retrieveStuff];
}

- (void)retrieveStuff
{
    // I'll assume you are making a NSURLConnection to a web service here, and you are using the "old" methods instead of +[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest...]
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWith...];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Do stuff with what you have retrieved here
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushSegueToBlueScreen"
           sender:nil];
}
```

If you just want to simulate first what will happen, you can try this:

```
- (IBAction)loadStuff:(id)sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
    [self retrieveStuff];
}

- (void)retrieveStuff
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 // seconds
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(hideProgressHUDAndPush)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}

- (void)hideProgressHUDAndPush
{
    // Do stuff with what you have retrieved here
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushSegueToBlueScreen"
                              sender:nil];
}
```

**EDIT:** You can try this GCD block for downloading a single image. I think you can just tinker around with this so you can support downloading multiple images.

```
- (IBAction)loadStuff:(id)sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                        // ... download image here
                        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path
                                                          atomically:YES];

                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushSegueToBlueScreen"
                                                                      sender:nil];
                                       });
                    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a NSURLConnection, so the second option would be better for me. I don't need to wait for a connection, I need to wait for the second view controller (blue). In that class I download some images from the internet so if I push the button on the main view controller, it needs to show the loading HUD, and after the blue view controller images are loaded, the HUD needs to dissappear and the blue one needs to pop up.

Comment: The problem is that you give "seconds", but I don't know how long it will take to download all the images...

Comment: By any chance, are you using some "framework" (e.g. ASIHTTPRequest) to download your images? If so, there should be some method or block where you can put the actions that should be done after the connection has finished. My point is, since you are downloading images, you should dismiss the progress HUD and push to blue screen after downloading; you should not use option 2 since the time to finish downloading can vary.

Comment: I'm not using ASIHTTPRequest on this one, I'm using the normal NSFileManager and [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];